# Pyramid: cyrillic letters in url shows "A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator." in debug mode

Tags: python, pyramid

I have articles with cyrillic letters in it's text and title text. The url of the article is

```
/%s/%s % (article.id, article.title.replace(' ', '_'))
```

And when I try to open this article it shows me

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Nothing about error or else. And all this in debug mode.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylons-discuss/zVEssUC_5KU), try upgrading pyramid_debugtoolbar to the most recent
version (0.9.8)